# How can a state be cleared when moving away from a page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created a Quiz app that tracks the correct answers in state called correct_answer. The issue is when the user leaves one quiz and moves on to the next one, The quiz answers are still stored from the last quiz.

I have tried using LOCATION_CHANGE from react-router-redux, but I am not sure I am using it correctly.

````
    import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from "react-router-redux";
    const initialState = {
      questions: [],
      answers: [],
      correct_answer: []
    };

    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_QUESTIONS":
          return { ...state, questions: action.payload };
        case "GET_ANSWERS":
          return { ...state, answers: action.payload };
        case "CORRECT_ANSWER":
          return {
            ...state,
            correct_answer: [...state.correct_answer, action.payload]
          };
        case LOCATION_CHANGE:
          return {state = initialState};
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }```

The app needs to clear the correct_answers state anytime the user moves away from the page.
````

Comment: You need to write action (clearAnswers f.e.) and then  in reducer - clear your value. Your action should be called in place where you need to clear data, f.e. in ComponentWIllUnmount() method. You don't need Location_change, just create simple action.

Comment: How would I write that in the reducer?

Comment: case "RESET_APP":
      return {
        ...state
      };  Like this?

Comment: yep, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the redux store is an omnipresent data structure. The data persists regardless of any ui changes in your app, which includes local state changes in a component and mounting/unmounting components (unless you tear down your reducer, but that's not what you're doing at all).

As mentioned in the comments, it's your job to clear your state. Create an action that will reset the reducer. How you implement it is based on your exact implementation of your Quiz component(s).

How does mounting/unmounting/prop changes work when you switch quizes? Are you mounting an entirely new component or are you feeding new data into an existing component?

If the next quiz is an entirely new instance, then you call it when you unmount the prior quiz:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.resetQuizState() // your action that resets the data in your store
}
```

If it is the same component but new props are passed in:

```
handleNextQuizClick() {
  this.props.resetQuizState()
  // and then rest of data manipulation/calling/parsing
}

render() {
  return (
    <button onClick={this.handleNextQuizClick}>
      next quiz
    </button>
}
```